# What is the best way for storage something in Ionic?

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have a login service. And  i have to store userCustomerId and userName when user logged in. Because i'm using these datas on another pages (cart, accountInfo etc.).

How should I store these datas?

> version : ionic 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use the Ionic Storage functionality. It allows you to store key/value pairs as well as JSON.

In the Ionic docs you will find how to use it:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/